# Star system data structure implementation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I'm attempting to implement a useful data structure for modeling a star system. I was told that a tree-structure might be best, but that neither std nor Qt have those out-of-the-box.

Up until now, I've been working with something like the following to model celestial bodies with their orbiters:

```
typedef struct Body {
   /* various data*/
   QList<Body> orbiters;
} Body;
```

This is useful because it lets me quickly access what orbits a particular body. However, it does not allow me to determine, just having the object in question, what the body is orbiting! Is it possible to add some sort of "parent-pointer" to the above to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you using `typedef` for structures in C++? Structure names acts as types just like class names. In fact, the only difference between a structure and a class in C++ is the default visibility (`public` for structures, `private` for classes).

Comment: You can extend your `Body` structure with the new member variable that will point the orbit it belongs to.

Comment: I would also tend to classes. You can setup a parent-child-tree list with classes easily. Just have a class solarsystem having a list of planets having a list of orbiters ....

Comment: @SebastianLange And one most likely want to use pointers / `std::shared_ptr` in this case.

Comment: @Paranaix to stay in QtWorld we could use QSharedPointer (just the Qt reimp), but shared pointers is a good idea which would make the implementation a lot easier.

Comment: @Joachim I'm using `typedef struct` out of habit. As you say, it's almost the same as a class. @vahancho Yeah, but I'm unsure about the specifics of that. Will just a pointer do? What happens when I use `foreach` to access things? @Sebastian How does a `QSharedPointer` differ from a normal pointer?

Comment: @AbuDhabi Shouldnt make a big difference at all, but IMO one should always stay with std if it does not introduces any kind of big trouble. The habit of Qt wanting to be a standart library and providing such elementary stuff is one thing which really bugs me about that library.

Comment: @Abu Dhabi Shared pointers automatically delete the object when the last pointer disappears -- you will need to manage your memory more carefully with regular pointers. What do you mean by *"What happens when I use `foreach` to access things?"* -- I don't think anything special happens, but if you have C++11 support, you can use range-based for-loops instead of the `foreach` macro.

Comment: @JKSH 1. If I make a pointer to an object residing within a QList, will it stay pointing at the object for all legitimate operations that the QList does, short of removing the object from it? 2. Does using `foreach` make a copy of the object, or does it just give you access to the object within the QList?

Comment: @AbuDhabi: 1. If you do that, your pointers will become invalid if your QList gets reallocated (because the objects will be moved to a different memory location). You don't make a pointer to an object residing within a QList; you allocate your object on the heap and store the pointer to your heap-allocated object in the QList. 2. You need to tell `foreach` what type to use. If you tell it to use a value-type, then it will make a copy. If you tell it to use a reference-type, then it won't make a copy. (You don't have to worry about this if your QList stores pointers)

Comment: @Paranaix Qt 5 has changed direction and encourages developers to use STL where possible (see http://www.mail-archive.com/development@qt-project.org/msg01603.html ) Note, however, that Qt types do a lot more than their STL counterparts, e.g. QVector has copy-on-write while std::vector doesn't; QString's API makes string manipulation much cleaner and much more expressive than std::wstring's API.

Comment: @JKSH This is what I was afraid of - I don't know how to do this, and that is the essence of my question: How do I do this pointer-thing so it works and doesn't break?

Comment: Why not using something like SQL to model your star system? Do you need a very high performance? A SQL database can be embedded in a Qt Application with SqlLite

Comment: @galinette Yes, I need high performance - the intent is to model these in realtime. I'm already running into performance issues (high-precision ellipse drawing and modelling hundreds of asteroids).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple tree implementation, based on the [Qt object model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/objecttrees.html) (all QObjects have the ability to form trees)

```
class Body {
public:
    // When a Body is constructed, it automatically remembers its parent
    // and adds itself to its parent's list of children.
    Body(const QString& name, Body* parent = nullptr) {
        this->m_name = name;
        this->m_parent = parent;
        if (parent != nullptr) {
            parent->m_orbiters.append(this);
        }
    }

    // When a parent is deleted, the children are automatically deleted too.
    // If you use shared pointers, you don't need this destructor.
    ~Body() {
        qDeleteAll(m_orbiters);
    }

    // Getters
    QString name() const           { return m_name;     }
    Body* parent() const           { return m_parent;   }
    QList<Body*> children() const  { return m_orbiters; }

private:
    QString m_name;
    Body* m_parent;
    QList<Body*> m_orbiters;
};
```

Build a tree:

```
// The sun doesn't orbit anything
Body* sun = new Body("Sun");

// The planets orbit the sun
Body* mercury = new Body("Mercury", sun);
Body* earth   = new Body("Earth",   sun);
Body* mars    = new Body("Mars",    sun);

// The moons orbit the planets
Body* moon   = new Body("Moon",   earth);
Body* phobos = new Body("Phobos", mars);
Body* deimos = new Body("Deimos", mars);
```

Print a list of bodies that orbit the sun directly:

```
auto planets = sun->children();
for (Body* planet : planets) {
    qDebug() << planet->name();
}
// Output:
//  "Mercury"
//  "Earth"
//  "Mars"
```

Delete the tree:

```
// The sun's destructor deletes the planets;
// the planets' destructor deletes the moons
delete sun;
```

By the way, it sounds like you don't have much experience with data structures and pointers. I recommend you read a good tutorial/book on these 2 topics -- your C++ life will become much much easier as a result.

Comment: There is no reason for double indirection - the `QList` internally holds pointers to objects, so just put the objects there. Then you don't need to do *any manual memory management whatsoever*. Your code looks like C-with-objects, it's rather poor C++. Returning a list of objects by value is cheap due to `QList`'s implicit sharing implementation.

Comment: Do you mean using `QList<Body>` instead of `QList<Body*>`? `Body::children()` will then return *copies* of the child objects. Yes, they are implicitly shared at first, but if I modify a Body in the list (e.g. to add a new orbiter), the list will detach and I will be modifying a clone. The original will remain unchanged. How do you propose to address this?

Comment: "the list will detach and I will be modifying a clone." That's fine. Why do you worry about it? If the list is modified then you're already paying the cost of doing so, you don't modify it for no reason I hope. You should also have a `const QList<Body> & children() const` accessor to enforce the cases where you don't intend to modify the list.

Comment: I wasn't worried about the *cost* of making copies. Instead, I was asking: What API do you propose for letting someone *modify an existing Body* in the list?

Comment: A non-const accessor returning a reference :) This then obviates the one returning the list by value. Simply have two reference accessors, a const one returning a const reference, and a non-const one returning a non-const reference.

Comment: Yes, that works. :) I encourage you to post your implementation + examples as a standalone answer.

Answer (score 1):

[QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#details) is based on a hierarchical structure: citing from that link

> QObjects organize themselves in object trees. When you create a QObject with another object as parent, the object will automatically add itself to the parent's children() list. The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its destructor. You can look for an object by name and optionally type using findChild() or findChildren().

Then I would suggest to change your class, inheriting from QObject:

```
class Body : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Body(QString name, QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
      setObjectName(name);
   }
   /* keep orbiters in children(), find them by name */
   /* parent() give you the relation you're missing now... */
   ...
};
```

After the change you will gain all the benefits of a well though object system, and the goodies like advanced communication via signal/slot, etc...